# IOS/Objective-C: Simple Library in Objective-C to Make SImple Bar Graphs without Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts

I would like to incorporate some relatively simple graphs in my app.  The state of the art libraries seem to be written in Swift and require cocoapods such as [Daniel Gindi's Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts).  For a variety of reasons,  I don't want to use cocoapods and would prefer to keep the app purely in Objective-C.  But I'm having a hard time finding a library in Objective-C that does not use cocoapods.

Coreplot from a few years ago seems like it would have fit the bill, however, it seems to have been [rewritten in Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1057-core-plot-tutorial-getting-started).

Can anyone recommend a relatively lightweight Objective-C library that does not use cocoapods for creating simple charts?  (I realize this may seem subjective but there are many highly-upvoted older questions on SO about libraries for charts.)  Other than the old Coreplot, however, none of the suggestions seem to be in Objective-C and not require cocoapods.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You don't have to use CocoaPods, just go to the GitHub repo for the framework, download it as a zip file and add the files to your project.

Comment: Any framework?  Or do you mean Charts or Coreplot? ( I've found it difficult in the past to install frameworks that want you to use cocoapods as they don't tell you about settings you might need to change.)

Comment: For example, right now I tried to import Coreplot, but Xcode does not recognize my import statement #import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h" possibly because I cannot figure out the right HeaderSourcePath

Comment: @user6631314 have you found any framework ?